# How can I create my own route using CoreLocation and mapKit?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, annotations, mapkit, core-location

I know that CoreLocation already has a method that does the difference between two dots that have(Latitude and Longitude), but this route is the closets route between the dots. What I want is to draw my own route.

Do you guys have any idea how I could do that?

Comment: What route do you want?  Do you want a route that follows roads?  Bike paths?  Victor airways?